# ORA-01438 Issue while performing dup search

Tags: oracle, sqr

I am a developer with SQL Server experience. We have one legacy application which uses SQR and Oracle to perform a weekly duplicate record search. We got an error while performing this search after 14 years. It says 'ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column'. When I googled that error, I found out that it is related to a numeric field and the value passed is larger than it can hold. I can increase the size but don't know for which one. Since no one supports Oracle here, I am trying to trouble shoot this error and found people using

```
alter system set events='1438 trace name Errorstack forever,level 10';
```

I would like to know if this is the right way to find out which sql is failing?
Also what does it alter and what is level 10? Anything that I should consider before running this query in production? Is there something I need to roll back after performing this query? I was told that if I do SQL> insert into test values (100000000000000000,'test','test');  where 10000000000000000 is invalid then it will throw generic Oracle message ORA-01438. But in the trace file, it would show ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column. So, where would the trace file be generated?

```
Current SQL statement for this session:
insert into test values (100000000000000000,'test','test').
```

Please let me know if I am not in the right path.

Comment: Well, what is the data definition for the 1st column?

Answer (score 0):

Use DBMS_MONITOR to enabling trace for the session affected. This will contain all SQL and errors and bind variables, if you enable it.